# Sharing through APEX Code

Tags: salesforce

I am getting invalid Bind Expression when i am executing the below code .Can some explain me if i am making any mistake.

public void ShareAPRwithAdvisor(List aprs){

```
    List<APR__Share> APRShareList = new List<APR__Share>();
    List<APR__c> apraccList=new List<APR__c>([SELECT id,APR_AdvisorName__c FROM APR__c WHERE Id IN:aprs]);
    List<Account> usrlist=new List<Account>([SELECT id,Advisor_User__pc FROM Account WHERE Id IN:apraccList]);

    System.debug('APR********************'+aprs);
    // System.debug('APR********************'+aprs.APR_AdvisorName__c);

    for(APR__c apr : aprs){
         if(apr.APR_AdvisorName__c != null){
            APR__Share aprshare = new APR__Share();
            aprshare.ParentID = apr.ID;
            aprshare.UserorGroupID = usrlist.Advisor_User__pc;
            aprshare.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
            APRShareList.add(aprshare);

        }
        System.debug('APRShareList'+APRShareList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"usrlist.Advisor_User__pc" -- Shouldn't this be "usrlist.Advisor_User__c"?

Comment: it is person account type.